# How to Classify $2$-Plane Bundles over $S^2$?

Tags: differential-geometry, low-dimensional-topology, geometric-topology

I'm curious how one can classify the bundles over a given manifold. I recently read [this paper](http://www.brynmawr.edu/math/people/melvin/papers/M84.pdf) on classifying $2$-sphere bundles over compact surfaces. A lot of the concepts went over my head since I'm still having trouble doing more "trivial" classifications.

To get used to harder classifications, I'm hoping to get used to doing easier ones first. Thus, I'm curious how one can classify the $2$-plane bundles over $S^2$. To be honest, I'm not sure how to even approach such a problem.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A vector bundle on $S^2$ can be constructed by gluing two trivial vector bundles over $S^2_+$ and $S^2_-$, the closed hemispheres. This is called the *clutching construction*; see, for example, Husemoller's book.

The «gluing instructions» are a map from the equator, a cicle $S^1$, to $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb R)$, and the result depends only on the homotopy class of this map $S^1\to\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb R)$. Therefore, to do the classification you want, one needs to classify these up to homotopy.

Working this out, you end up with a bijection between isomorphism classes of $2$-dimensional vector bundles on $S^2$and elements of $\pi_1(\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb R))$. The latter group is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: So given this clutching construction, we just consider all possible ways of gluing and then show which ones are the same up to homotopy?

Comment: Yes. This is explained in Husemoller's book and many other places —there is even a Wikipedia page on cluthing!— and they do a better jobs than what I could do here :)

Comment: This seems like a really useful construction! Does this construction work for classifying bundles on any (or most) manifolds?

Comment: I would imagine yes, provided you have a simple decomposition as a CW complex or a cover by charts with intersections you understand. The above argument works because the inthersection of the two hemispheres is a circle, but would fail in general with too complicated or unknown intersections.

Comment: I want to add a subtle point to this answer: you only get an isomorphism between 2-dimensional vector bundles and $\pi_1(GL_2(\mathbb R))$ if you pick a distinguished point in $S^2$ and trivialize the bundle over that point, which is equivalent to picking a preferred orientation. Otherwise you get an isomorphism to the set of *unbased* maps $S^2 \to BGL_2(\mathbb R)$, and this is a set that receives a surjective map (not an isomorphism) from $\pi_1(GL_2(\mathbb R))$. The map identifies $n$ and $-n$ together, so that we're left with the natural numbers $\{0,1,2,...\}$ as a set.

Comment: I'm teaching the class on fiber bundles again and still working on learning this better! To add another explanation, principal $G$-bundles on $S^n$ are classified by orbits of $\pi_{n-1}(G)$ under the conjugation action of $\pi_0(G)$. This corresponds to unbased maps $[S^n,BG]$, which are a quotient of based maps $[S^n,BG]_*$ by the action of $\pi_1(BG) = \pi_0(G)$ on the higher homotopy groups $\pi_n(BG) = \pi_{n-1}(G)$. In the case of $\pi_1(GL_2(\mathbb R))$, that action is the action of $\mathbb Z/2$ on $\mathbb Z$ by negation.